# R: Aggregating a list of column names and row numbers based off of a condition in a data frame

Tags: r

Scaled down my data frame looks like this:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |   Label1   |   Label2    |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 |      T     |     F       |
| 2 |      F     |     F       |
| 3 |      T     |     T       |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

I want to aggregate and return this in a list/vector such that for all false values my list contains something along the lines of (column name, row number) so for example {(Label1, 2)(Label2, 1)(Label2, 2)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(Label1 = c("T","F","T"), Label2 = c("F", "F", "T"))
with(data.frame(which(df == "F", arr.ind = TRUE)), paste(names(df)[col], row, sep = ", "))
#[1] "Label1, 2" "Label2, 1" "Label2, 2"
```

Comment: The outcome in your solution matches my expected outcome perfectly.